# How to Call Custom Perl Module in a Script

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu

I am installing mireap software on my Linux VM (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mireap/). After installation, I am unable to run the software as I am always getting the error that FFW1.pm module needs to be installed; however, the module is present in lib directory. The script failed to call the module from the library. I will really appreciate if you help me in this regard. The steps which I performed are there in the image.

Comment: Have you looked into Perl documentation? [use lib 'path_to/lib';](https://perldoc.perl.org/lib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "lib directory".

If you mean the the module is in a directory named `lib`, and that this directory is a subdirectory of the one in which the script is located, then this should be added to the script:

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/lib";
```